# Recommendations for Blue Green Deployment Testing with Minimal Assertions in Cron-Based Batch Jobs for Higher environment

Tags: testing, devops, production-environment, blue-green-deployment, test-pyramid

I am working on a batch application where we utilize Blue Green deployment strategies. Our application comprises three cron-based batch jobs. During the Blue Green deployment process, we execute a certain number of test cases. However, in higher environments, we have limited control over input data, resulting in minimal assertions during testing. Our deployment process primarily involves executing batch jobs and verifying their successful completion.

I am seeking recommendations on what tasks should be executed as part of the Blue Green deployment process given our scenario. For lower environments, we do have distinct set of fictional tests to validate business logic.